# Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug'

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I have encountered this issue after installing updates of android studio. 
Tried updating whatever android studio console recommends to update gradle versions and other settings. After all the updates and downloading i am here at this issue.

---

Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.

Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

```
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
:app:compileDebugNdk NO-SOURCE
:app:compileDebugSources
error processing /home/sajid/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.ow2.asm/asm/6.0/bc6fa6b19424bb9592fe43bbc20178f92d403105/asm-6.0.jar

java.lang.RuntimeException
at org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.visitModule(ClassVisitor.java:148)
at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readModule(ClassReader.java:731)
at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:632)
at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:500)
at com.android.builder.desugaring.DesugaringClassAnalyzer.analyze(DesugaringClassAnalyzer.java:144)
at com.android.builder.desugaring.DesugaringClassAnalyzer.analyzeJar(DesugaringClassAnalyzer.java:92)
at com.android.builder.desugaring.DesugaringClassAnalyzer.analyze(DesugaringClassAnalyzer.java:63)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DesugarIncrementalTransformHelper.lambda$getInitalGraphData$4(DesugarIncrementalTransformHelper.java:150)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1424)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)

java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.getThrowableException(ForkJoinTask.java:593)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.reportException(ForkJoinTask.java:677)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.join(ForkJoinTask.java:720)
at com.android.ide.common.internal.WaitableExecutor.waitForTasksWithQuickFail(WaitableExecutor.java:146)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DesugarIncrementalTransformHelper.getInitalGraphData(DesugarIncrementalTransformHelper.java:162)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DesugarIncrementalTransformHelper.makeDesugaringGraph(DesugarIncrementalTransformHelper.java:130)
at com.google.common.base.Suppliers$NonSerializableMemoizingSupplier.get(Suppliers.java:160)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DesugarIncrementalTransformHelper.getDependenciesPaths(DesugarIncrementalTransformHelper.java:231)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexArchiveBuilderTransform.getD8DesugaringCacheInfo(DexArchiveBuilderTransform.java:461)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexArchiveBuilderTransform.transform(DexArchiveBuilderTransform.java:375)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:239)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:235)
at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:230)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:50)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:124)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:113)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:73)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:59)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:256)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:249)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:238)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:663)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:597)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException
at org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.visitModule(ClassVisitor.java:148)
at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readModule(ClassReader.java:731)
at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:632)
at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:500)
at com.android.builder.desugaring.DesugaringClassAnalyzer.analyze(DesugaringClassAnalyzer.java:144)
at com.android.builder.desugaring.DesugaringClassAnalyzer.analyzeJar(DesugaringClassAnalyzer.java:92)
at com.android.builder.desugaring.DesugaringClassAnalyzer.analyze(DesugaringClassAnalyzer.java:63)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DesugarIncrementalTransformHelper.lambda$getInitalGraphData$4(DesugarIncrementalTransformHelper.java:150)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1424)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)

:app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug FAILED
```

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug'.

  > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 5.0.
See https://docs.gradle.org/4.6/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 13s

22 actionable tasks: 20 executed, 2 up-to-date

---

I have tried the following solution and nothing works:

- deleted this file the rebuild (/home/sajid/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.ow2.asm/asm/6.0/bc6fa6b19424bb9592fe43bbc20178f92d403105/asm-6.0.jar)
- Set javaMaxHeapSize "4g" in dexOptions in build.gradle
- Set multiDexEnabled true in defaultConfig in build.gradle
- Deleted .gradle folder from project directory and clean, rebuild, restart, sync.

Any help will be very much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Please add more logs. Can't help you without checking them all.

Comment: @Mohsen i have added all the logs. Please have a look now. Thanks

Comment: @Mohsen can you please answer, I had added all the logs. Any hint?

Comment: @SajidZeb: in build section resolve only compiler error.

Comment: @SajidZeb Sorry. It's hard to tell what causes the issue. However, you can try updating the Android Studio if you already didn't. This will be the only best solution we have now.

Comment: Thanks @Mohsen but this issue has been raised after upgrading to Gradle 4.6. The build is working on the earlier version. I have the code in the other branch. and i am able to run code from that branch

Comment: If it works on earlier versions, perhaps something related to gradle causes the issue. I suggest reporting this issue for the next builds and using an older version of 4.6.

Comment: Right. I have actually deleted the .gradle folder from both places:
- app project
- /home/user/.gradle
Its now taking time in downloading all dependencies. Lets c if it resolve this or not.

Comment: getting same error after deleting .gradle folders and downloading dependencies again.

Answer (score 0):

i don't have enough reputation to comment yet, so i'm commenting here. I had the same problem as you and my issue was the android-mockito (the last version). I didn't found a solution yet, but apparently it was some problem with java 8 bytecode. I hope this give you some light. Good luck.

Comment: It would be a good idea to post some more details, if you still know them. For example the Java 8 bytecode error message or such.

Comment: I'm not sure about this, since i'm a beginner developer. The discussion is here: https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/1882

It's about lombok, but the error was very similar, the solutions presented there didn't help me, because removing Java 8 compileOption was causing error on ButterKnife.

Comment: Yes i second you @AlexanderCavalheiroBecker. I worked on Test units and working fine on previous gradle and android studio version.
I was working on gradle 4.4. and in build.gradle it was android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3. Working fine. 
I went to upgrade android studio along with gradle updates to 4.6. and in build.gradle to android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1. After these updates i am getting this issue. I can run the code from the previous branch which contains gradle 4.4 and 3.1.3.

Comment: I think that for now is better to downgrade the version of gradle if you really need the tests. I haven't found a solution so far.

Comment: @AlexanderCavalheiroBecker yes i think now this is the only solution. as after deleting the .gradle folders. and downloading dependencies. same error. no success.

Comment: @SajidZeb If you find a solution please let me know. =)

Comment: sure, @AlexanderCavalheiroBecker if you found it. please you also. Thanks for your time. I appreciate